# How to authenticate‎ a user in Joomla via AJAX / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, joomla

I would like to be able to authenticate a user in Joomla via an AJAX call so I can create the error effect if the login is incorrect and redirect the user if it is correct.

I would prefer to do it through the JQuery's `.ajax` API.

Also, do I need to somehow initialize JQuery or it is there already you just have to use "JQuery" instead of the "$"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can use Joomla's login options for Ajax login authentication.

collect your user name and password via post and set to the array.

```
   $options = array();
   $options['remember'] = JRequest::getBool('remember', false);
   $data['username'] = JRequest::getVar('username', '', 'method', 'username');
   $data['password'] = JRequest::getString('password', '', 'post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
   $credentials = array();
   $credentials['username'] = $data['username'];
   $credentials['password'] = $data['password'];
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $error = $app->login($credentials, $options);
   if (!JError::isError($error)) {
    // login success
    }
  else{
    //Failed attempt
   }
```

The above code section can be write inside any of your controller function if you have any custom component. If your are using `Joomla3.x` you can use `com_ajax` for this task .

```
 var data = "";//set your user name and password
jQuery.ajax ({

        type: "POST",

        url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&task=loginauth",

        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
         }
          });
```

When you include the jQuery library  in your application then just access it with `jQuery`
`'$'` is used for moo-tools in Joomla.For including jQuery library you can just edit the template file `templates/yourtemplate/index.php`

Hope its helps..

Comment: `If your are using Joomla3.x you can use com_ajax for this task.` >> You can also use com_ajax for Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 but you need to manually download it (github) and install it ;)

Comment: So, if I'm using 3.x I don't need the PHP code? Just the call to index.php?option=com_ajax&task=loginauth with the data object that has username and password?

Comment: @kidalex In anyway you have to add loginauth() on the controller and above php code inside that.